# No main method detected

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

The compiler keeps saying there is no main method but there is one:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
class StarWarsFinal

{
    final static Map<String, String> firstNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
    firstNameMap.put("A", "Cho");
    firstNameMap.put("B", "R2");
    firstNameMap.put("C", "C-3po");
    firstNameMap.put("D", "Yod");
    firstNameMap.put("E", "Nas");
    firstNameMap.put("F", "Slea");
    firstNameMap.put("G", "Jan");
    firstNameMap.put("H", "Zhur");
    firstNameMap.put("I", "Boba");
    firstNameMap.put("J", "Thre");
    firstNameMap.put("K", "Bib");
    firstNameMap.put("L", "Kit");
    firstNameMap.put("M", "Kyp");
    firstNameMap.put("N", "Gonk");
    firstNameMap.put("O", "Zlung");
    firstNameMap.put("P", "Adi");
    firstNameMap.put("Q", "Nat");
    firstNameMap.put("R", "Ru");
    firstNameMap.put("S", "Cla");
    firstNameMap.put("T", "Kir");
    firstNameMap.put("U", "Obi");
    firstNameMap.put("V", "Ken");
    firstNameMap.put("W", "Ziro");
    firstNameMap.put("X", "Zev");
    firstNameMap.put("Y", "Tavion");
    firstNameMap.put("Z", "Jar");
    }


    final static Map<String, String> lastNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
    lastNameMap.put("A", "tzki");
    lastNameMap.put("B", "hut");
    lastNameMap.put("C", "der");
    lastNameMap.put("D", "kzos");
    lastNameMap.put("E", "vos");
    lastNameMap.put("F", "vader");
    lastNameMap.put("G", "thrawn");
    lastNameMap.put("H", "mesk");
    lastNameMap.put("I", "thuo");
    lastNameMap.put("J", "skywalker");
    lastNameMap.put("K", "D2");
    lastNameMap.put("L", "maul");
    lastNameMap.put("M", "sith");
    lastNameMap.put("N", "muzzar");
    lastNameMap.put("O", "jusik");
    lastNameMap.put("P", "horn");
    lastNameMap.put("Q", "phisto");
    lastNameMap.put("R", "farlander");
    lastNameMap.put("S", "dunhaussan");
    lastNameMap.put("T", "jar");
    lastNameMap.put("U", "binks");
    lastNameMap.put("V", "lbis");
    lastNameMap.put("W", "gnarzlo");
    lastNameMap.put("X",  "anakin");
    lastNameMap.put("Y",  "ackbur");
    lastNameMap.put("Z", "axmis"); 
    }
    final static Map<String, String> jobMap = new HashMap<>();
    static{

    jobMap.put("Jan","Clone");
    jobMap.put("Feb","Bounty Hunter");
    jobMap.put("Mar","Droid");
    jobMap.put("Apr","Jedi Knight");
    jobMap.put("May","Gungan");
    jobMap.put("Jun","Gangster");
    jobMap.put("Jul","commander");
    jobMap.put("Aug","ewok");
    jobMap.put("Sep","Queen");
    jobMap.put("Oct","Empirer");
    jobMap.put("Nov","Darth");
    jobMap.put("Dec","captain");


    }

  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
      String[] planet = null, rank = null, rebbelion = null, letter1 = null, letter2= null , Map , HashMap;


     Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ); //scanner initilized


    planet = new String[11]; //Planet options  

    planet[0] = "Alderaan";
    planet[1] = "Bespin";
    planet[2] = "Coruscant";
    planet[3]= "Forest moon of Endor";
    planet[4] = "Hoth";
    planet[5] = "Kamino";
    planet[6] = "Kashyyk";
    planet[7] = "Mustafar";
    planet[8] = "Yavin";
    planet[9] = "DEATH STAR";//Planet options  -END




        System.out.println("Welcome to the Star Wars name generator");
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");     //Name Generation
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
        String newFirst = firstNameMap.get(firstName.toUpperCase().substring(0,1));         //Name Generation (i want to take the first letter of there input and get the output from letter1 matching that # ie c = letter1 [2]  a= letter1 [0])
        System.out.println("What is your last name?");      //Name Generation
        String lastName = input.nextLine(); //Name Generation (i want to take the first letter of there input and get the output from letter2 matching that # ie c = letter2 [2]  a= letter2 [0])
        String newLast = lastNameMap.get (lastName.toUpperCase().substring(0,1));
        System.out.println("What is your Birth month(first 3 letters)?");     //Name Generation
        String month = input.nextLine();
        String job = jobMap.get(firstName.toUpperCase().substring(0,3));


    System.out.println("If you had to choose 1)dark or 2)light side? please input the number"); //Selection of Dark or Light side
    int side = input.nextInt();
                                       //Selection of Dark or Light side

      System.out.println("There are now several places you could live please choose one of the following by number:");    //Planet selections
                System.out.println("1) Alderaan 2) Bespin 3) Coruscant 4) Forest moon of Endor 5) Hoth ");                          //Planet selections
                System.out.println("6) Kamino 7) Kashyyk 8) Mustafar 9) Yavin 10)DEATHSTAR");                                       //Planet selections
                String location =input.nextLine();


        if (side == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("You Have chosen to be part of the dark side!");

                System.out.println("You "+ newFirst + newLast +" now fight for the dark side  As a proud "+ job +"of the"+ location +"Good luck against your enemy's and may the force be with you");
        }


        else
        {
            System.out.println("You are now part of the light side!");

            System.out.println("You "+ newFirst + newLast +" now fight for the light side  As a proud "+ job +"of the"+ location +"Good luck against your enemy's and may the force be with you");
        } 



        System.out.println("Thank you for doing the starwars name generator!");
  }
}
```

I don't know why it won't read it, because it was working earlier. I'mm using NetBeans as IDE.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Class doesn't have to be public.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True, I just tested it, because I didn't believe you!

Comment: So, then it has to be the wrong package (move to default), although NetBeans should report that to you and offer refactoring. Other than that I don't see what could be wrong.

Comment: @haywire Skepticism is a positive trait in our line of work :)

Comment: Your code works if I run it in IntelliJ. There is maybe something wrong on how you're compiliing and calling your application. Use `javac StarWarsFinal.java` to compile it and `java -cp . StarWarsFinal`to run it (if you're currently in the directory there the class file is).

Comment: Which Netbeans version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the program.

I did the following:

```
[steve@newbox tmp]$ cat > StarWarsFinal.java
<paste-program-from-question>
[steve@newbox tmp]$ javac StarWarsFinal.java 
[steve@newbox tmp]$ java StarWarsFinal 
Welcome to the Star Wars name generator
What is your first name?
^D
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at StarWarsFinal.main(StarWarsFinal.java:112)
[steve@newbox tmp]$
```

---

From this we must conclude that the problem you are experiencing is one of the following:

- You are not compiling it properly.
- You are not running it properly.
- There is something *non-standard* in the way that NetBeans is deciding that a class is runnable.  (This is highly unlikely ... IMO)
- Maybe you are doing something else that you haven't mentioned ...

---

For the record:

- It is NOT necessary for the class to be declared as `public` for it to be runnable, at least when you run it from the command line using the `java` command.
- It is not a Java compilation error for there to be no main method.  It is a runtime error.  A class only *needs* a `main` method if you are going to attempt to run it.  The compiler has no way of knowing if you are *going to* do that, so it cannot complain about it.
- The ["Hello World!" for the NetBeans IDE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html) page runs you through the steps of compiling and running a simple program using NetBeans.  Maybe this will give you some clues as to what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You are at least able to run it (like me). He is not. So in how far does this help?

Comment: @haywire - it shows him a simple way to compile and run his program that actually works.  It also gives some leads as to why it is not be working for him.  How does that NOT help him???

Comment: yeah, ok I see! But he still isn't able to compile and run this program via Netbeans what I assume is his goal.

Comment: @haywire - Well unless he explains in detail *how* he is attempting to compile and run it using (we assume) NetBeans, there is not much more we can do to help him figure out what he is doing wrong.